# Ubuntu 12.04.5 erroneously applies static IP to all interfaces

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, dhcp, vmware-player, static-ip

First, I'll start by saying this is a virtual machine in VMWare Player and I’m using Ubuntu 12.04.5 instead of the newest version of Ubuntu because it’s being used in an educational environment to learn some vulnerability testing strategies and mechanisms, so upgrading to the newest version is not an option.

Now, here’s my issue: `ifconfig` shows the correct IP addresses for each interface, as follows in this screenshot:

[image: ifconfig screenshot]

And then, as you can see by the following screenshot, when I specify the interface in a `ping`, it is applying the static IP from `eth0` to `eth1` and `eth2`, despite what it says in `ifconfig`. eth1 is set up in VMWare as a bridged adapter, and `eth2` is NAT to replicate my host IP (I set up `eth2` when the Bridged adapter wasn’t working, don't necessarily need both).

[image]

I’ve been messing with this for hours and nothing seems to be working to get this virtual machine out to the Internet.

I need to maintain the static IP for my Kali and Windows 7 machines to be able to do nefarious deeds without actually affecting a live network, but I also need to be able to access the web as part of my packet filtering and monitoring misadventures. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!